# Como abrir opções de aplicativos após download

Tags: android, webview, download

Estou desenvolvendo um App utilizando o WebView, acesso um sistema já existente feito em PHP. Nele possuem links para download de arquivos PDF, consigo fazer os downloads direcionando para um navegador ou em outra codificação, faço o download direto, mas ao terminar não abre diretamente, teria como, após o termino do download em PDF abrir uma janela perguntando qual aplicativo o usuário quer usar para abrir o documento?

Obrigado!

Comment: " faço o download direto, mas ao terminar não abre diretamente" não seria algum ajuste no próprio navegador ou até mesmo na máquina do cliente?

Comment: Oi Luiz,
Essa opção que gostaria que abrisse para escolher o aplicativo, não passa pelo navegador, o usuário clica em um link dentro do aplicativo, faz o download do PDF no Smartphone, aparece na barra se status, mas se o usuário não prestar atenção, pode esquecer que já fez o download (mesmo sendo aviso por um Toast). Não sei se estou conseguindo explicar direito.
Obrigado